# Combining __setattr__ and __getattr__ causes infinite loop

Tags: python, class, infinite-loop, getattr, setattr

I'm trying to build a system where a base class is used for every other object. Every base object has a `_fields` dictionary internally where implementations of the base class can store their information.

Base class implementation is quite simple:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, fields=dict()):
        self._fields = fields
```

An implementation of the class can set the field in the `__init__` call to its `super()`.

What I'd like to add is that the fields are accessible as properties without having to add the `@property` decorator to a whole bunch of functions. I've overriden the `__getattr__` for this purpose in the base class like so:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, fields=dict()):
        self._fields = fields

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        elif name in self._fields:
            return self._fields.get(name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

Now an implementation for this class can work like this:

```
class A_impl(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A_impl, self).__init__(
                    fields=dict(
                    val_1="foo",
                    val_2="",
                    val_3="bar",
                )
            )
```

By which creating an implementation of this class gives you the options to do:

```
test = A_imp()
print test.val_1
print test.val_2
print test.val_3
```

Which returns

```
foo

bar
```

I can even override this via `@property` decorators, changing the class like so:

```
class A_impl(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A_impl, self).__init__(
                    fields=dict(
                    val_1="foo",
                    val_2="",
                    val_3="bar",
                )
            )

    @property
    def val_1(self):
        return self._fields.get('val_1') + "_getter"
```

Which allows me to manipulate the data for return. The only issue is that if I want to be able to **set** one of these field variables I have to implement the descriptor setter functions which also requires me to make the property descriptor which creates a lot of duplicate work (ie I have to define descriptors for ALL my fields which is what I want to avoid here.

I implemented the `__setattr__` function for the base class to solve the issue where if I manually implement a descriptor setter function it should be chosen over the default which is `self._field[name] = value`. The base class now looks like this (similar to the `__getattr__`):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, fields=dict()):
        self._fields = fields

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        elif name in self._fields:
            return self._fields.get(name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        elif name in self._fields:
            self._fields[name] = value
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

Now if I run the same code test again:

```
test = A_imp()
print test.val_1
print test.val_2
print test.val_3
```

It instantly gets stuck in an infinite loop, it starts at the `__setattr__` but jumps into the `__getattr__` right after and keeps looping that.

I've been reading a lot of questions on stackoverflow for this and couldn't figure it out, this is why I build this test case to cleanly figure it out. Hopefully someone's able to clarify this for me and help me solve the issue.

Comment: That `hasattr` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to check whether an object has an attribute other than actually trying to retrieve it. Thus,

```
hasattr(self, 'val_1')
```

actually tries to access `self.val_1`. If `self.val_1` isn't found through the normal means, it falls back on `__getattr__`, which calls `hasattr` again in an infinite recursion.

`hasattr` actually catches any exception, including `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, and returns `False`, so the exact way this manifests depends on precisely how many `__getattr__` calls are nested. Some `__getattr__` calls hit the `object.__getattribute__` case and raise an `AttributeError`; some hit the `elif name in self._fields: return self._fields.get(name)` case. If `self._fields` exists, this returns a value, but with your `__setattr__`, sometimes `self._fields` doesn't exist!

---

When your `__setattr__` tries to handle the `self._fields` assignment in `__init__`, it calls `hasattr(self, '_fields')`, which calls `__getattr__`. Now some `__getattr__` calls make two recursive `__getattr__` calls, one in `hasattr` and one in `elif name in self._fields`. Since `hasattr` is catching exceptions, this causes recursive calls exponential in the recursion depth instead of quickly either seeming to work or raising an exception.

---

Don't use `hasattr` in `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`. In general, be very careful about all attempts to access attributes inside the methods that handle attribute access.

Comment: So how would I go about this? I want precedence over the self implemented descriptors instead of always serving the self._field entries.

Comment: @Yonathan: `__getattr__` is only called if the "normal" lookup (through `__getattribute__`) doesn't find a value, so you don't actually have to check again. As for how to "be very careful" about attribute access in general, that usually involves delegating to `super().__getattribute__` or `super().__setattr__` for any attribute retrieval or assignment that needs to bypass your special logic.

Comment: But applying that like `if name in self._fields` and else it as `super().__(set|set)attr__(self, name[, value])` in the set and get attr functions for the base class causes the same recursion issues. I don't see how I could solve the "standard behavior first and otherwise check self._fields" issue. Right now precendence is taken for the `__(get|set)attr__` functions instead of implemented descriptors. Sorry I'm just missing how I could solve this issue.

Comment: @Yonathan: `self._fields` is an unsafe access in your current implementation. You could have `__getattr__` special-case `name=='_fields'` and raise an AttributeError immediately.

Comment: Still causes the same issues though. My other option was building custom descriptors and create them as objects sort of wrapping it away but i think that's pretty convoluted. A simple base class thst holds fields with information and being able to override setter and getter functions is what I'm after.